# Redefine a function after it is created in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, loops, switch-statement

I'm creating through a PHP loop (the reason of the loop is because I want more or less cases) a switch Javascript function, that outputs this:

```
function my_function(array_name) {
    switch (true) {
    case (array_name[1] < x < array_name[2]):
            console.log("between: 1 & 2");
            break;
    case (array_name[2] < x < array_name[3]):
            console.log("between: 2 & 3");
            break;
    default:
            console.log("none");
            break;
    }
}
```

Now when the document is loaded I create a Javascript array which contains the values I want to pass to the function.

```
var array_to_execute = [0,1000,2000,3000];
```

How can I call the function after this array is created passing these values? Something like:

```
my_function(array_to_execute);
```

That would result in executing:

```
    switch (true) {
    case (1000 < x < 2000):
            console.log("between: 1 & 2");
            break;
    case (2000 < x < 3000):
            console.log("between: 2 & 3");
            break;
    default:
            console.log("none");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: By the way, `array_name[1] < x < array_name[2]` won't work as you expect it to. You have to write it out as `array_name[1] < x && x < array_name[2]`.

Comment: As a side note, `switch(true) case(x) case(y)` is normally written as `if(x) else if(y)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call that you've got in mind (`my_function(array_to_execute)`) should be just fine!

The problems you're probably having are because:

```
case (array_name[1] < x < array_name[2]):
```

does not work the way you think it does. (It ends up comparing a truth value to a number.) Use this instead and you should be good to go:

```
case (array_name[1] < x && x < array_name[2]):
```

Comment: Thanks, simplier than I thought :)